# How did the Antarctic Plateau lose the kings' names it originally had?

Tags: toponymy, antarctica

The [Antarctic Plateau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Plateau) was originally named by its explorers:

- [Shackleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Shackleton) named it the *King Edward VII Plateau*, after the king of England.
- [Amundsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roald_Amundsen) named it the *King Haakon VII Plateau*, after the king of Norway.

Usually the original names for Antarctic features have stuck, but this feature now has a different name.  How did this happen?  Who renamed it?  When did the new name take hold?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Originally, there was a lot of confusion about Antarctic nomenclature, with many different countries making different claims and names at different times. For example, this is one notice from 1912:

> The plateau around the South Pole was named by Amundsen after King
>   Haakon VII. Sir Ernest Shackleton points out, very, very politely,
>   that Amundsen must have done this inadvertently. Sir Ernest says, in
>   commenting on the trip: “Here I would like to point out that Amundsen,
>   in taking possession and in planting the flag at the South Pole and
>   naming the plateau after King Haakon VII., must, I presume, be unaware
>   of the fact that we, on our expedition, named the same plateau after
>   King Edward VII., an error on his part in nomenclature which he will,
>   no doubt, remedy  when he is aware of the facts.
>
> Amundsen replies, also very politely, that Sir Ernest is mistaken in
>   supposing that his plateau is the one that holds the South Pole. The
>   Edward VII. plateau and the King Haakon VII. plateau are not one and
>   the same. The controversy may possibly develop into a bitter one, since
>   the boundaries of each plateau must necessarily be unknown at the
>   present time.

-- Current Literature, April, 1912

In 1928 Admiral Byrd started a series of explorations to remap the continent. He side-stepped the issue and simply labeled the area as the "Polar Plateau" on his maps. Later, by the time of the [International Geophysical Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Geophysical_Year), it was realized that "Antarctic Plateau" was necessary because "Polar Plateau" is ambiguous (which pole?)

Comment: Since the other pole is covered by ocean it can hardly have a plateau around it.

Comment: @Oldcat - Well, there are also the magnetic poles. They move around, but the south one, and occasionally [the north one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Magnetic_Pole), are over land. Plus the word "polar" is often used as an adjective meaning "near the pole", rather than describing a specific spot.

Comment: Oh these explorers! I can definitely see them getting to a *very polite* bout of fisticuffs over the matter...